# API REST Android Backslash in URI

Tags: java, android, rest, url, uri

I want to use this API REST method

> http://datos.santander.es/api/rest/datasets/control_flotas_estimaciones.json?query=ayto\:paradaId:454&data=ayto:paradaId,ayto:etiqLinea,ayto:tiempo1,ayto:destino1

If you see the URL, there is a param "ayto\:paradaId:454" that uses a backslash

When i try to use it in Android, I get a IllegalFormatException because of the backslash

```
HttpGet get = new
                 HttpGet("http://datos.santander.es/api/rest/datasets/control_flotas_estimaciones.json?query=ayto\:paradaId:454&data=ayto:paradaId,ayto:etiqLinea,ayto:tiempo1,ayto:destino1");
```

Is there any way that i can use this URL? Alternatives?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:**

I also tried to put `"ayto\\:paradaId"` with two backslash and i got the same exception when I get the URI...

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape the backslash:

```
"...query=ayto\\:paradaId..."
              ^^
```

To prove that this is only one character, you can check

```
"\\".length()
```

Comment: I also did it and I got the same exception! Sorry, I forgot to say that in my question!. Any other solution? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Bae: When you get an Exception, don't forget to post the exact message along with it's stacktrace and the relevant lines of code.